# Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

Tags: laravel

I have a simple Laravel 5.1 code and I'm getting the `ErrorException` `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()`. Here is the code:

```
public function boot()
  {
     $news = News::all()->take(5)->get();
     view()->share('sideNews', $news);

  }
```

Whenever I remove the `->get();` there, it works. It's my first time using `eloquent`. I remember when I'm using the query builder, I always add the `->get()` in the last line of the code. Am i doing it correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do not use the `all` method:

```php
public function boot()
{
    $news = News::take(5)->get();

    view()->share('sideNews', $news);
}
```

Comment: However, the error was being caused by the use of `->get()`, `take() / paginate()` they are "forms of" `get()`. There, I simple fix would be to drop the `->get()` method.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced this issue while **paginate()** function.

---

**Simple Solution**

Remove **`get()`** after **`paginate()`** or **`take()`**

---

**What cause this error?**

If we use **`get()`** function after **`paginate()`** or **`take()`** like **`paginate(5)->get()`** then this error will occur.

---

**Right way or Answer**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::paginate(5);
        return view('product.index',compact('products'));
    }
```